# form doesn't get filled with zombie.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, zombie.js

I am trying to use zombie.js to test my backbone application. Here is my code to fill the form.

```
this.browser.fill('Name', "title")
    .fill('Link', "http://url.com")
    .pressButton('Save', function(err) {
        me.browser.assert.success();
        console.log("Name" + me.browser.html('#name'));
        console.log("Link" + me.browser.html('#link'));
        console.log("Alert" + me.browser.html('.alert-danger'));
        done();
    });
});
```

Both the Name and Link are logged without any value and the alert shows that the Link and name are empty. Can someone tell me what am I going wrong?

I am using Bootstrap and underscore templates, here is the html code for the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="<%= model.escape('name') %>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label for="link" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Link</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="link" value="<%= model.escape('link') %>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-btn">Save</button>
      <a href=<% if(model.id > 0) { %>"#room/<%= model.id %>"<% } else { %>"#rooms/0"<% } %>><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: add your HTML code, it's more easy if you want some help

Comment: Added the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `name` attribute to your elements like this

```
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= model.escape('name') %>">
...
<input name="link" id="link" type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= model.escape('link') %>">
```

And pass the name as a parameter to your fill function

```
this.browser.fill('name', "title")
            .fill('link', "http://url.com")
```

Comment: Tried using name as well as id, but the inputs always remain empty. According to the documentation both CSS selectors and label text are supported.

If I use a random string as first argument, it fails with error that it can't find the input. Hence, in my case it is able to find the input but it just doesn't fill it.